# Redirect from www to non-www with 301 redirect in JBoss 7

Tags: java, http, jsf, redirect, jboss

I have a domain and want to redirect requests like "domain.com/blau" to "www.domain.com/blau" with an 301 redirect. I want to use the internal jboss Server  (jboss as 7) for that.

Comment: try checking external url from request instance

Comment: Do you mean a filter ? I thought more of something like apaches mod_alias. Wouldn't a java filter cost more Performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my problem:

```
<virtual-server name="foobarVirtualDomain">
    <alias name="foobar.com"/>
    <alias name="www.foobar.com"/>
    <rewrite pattern="^(.*)$" substitution="http://%1:%{SERVER_PORT}$1" flags="R=301,L">
        <condition test="%{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.+)$" flags="NC"/>
    </rewrite>
</virtual-server>
```